# Reliable and Cheap Document Scanner

Tags: scanner

I would like to buy a reliable and relatively cheap document scanner that I can use to scan my documents and get rid of the paper.

All I need is something with a feeder that can support at least 20 to 30 pages and works on a Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

What do you guys suggest? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/78538/home-document-scanner

Comment: wow, this neat scanner is awesome but unfortunately it does not scans A4 format! damn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have to say that Fujitsu makes the cheapest Mac compatible document scanners ([SnapScan](http://www.fujitsu.com/us/services/computing/peripherals/scanners/scansnap/s300m.html) Series). Prices range in the $180 - $300 range.

Answer (score 1):

**Doxie**

http://www.getdoxie.com/product/index.html